# Conduit's "await" receives Maybe. Why? And how to?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am interested in Conduit's `await :: Monad m => ConduitM i o m (Maybe i)`.

Can anyone explain why it happens and, in particular, how do I `yield` such an optional value or how do I write a producer/source that can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the upstream source was exhausted, the `await` conduit will start returning `Nothing` as the result and will not return anything but `Nothing` from now on. It indicates the termination of the upstream conduit so you can do some finalization job.

At the other end `yieldOr` indicates the termination of the downstream sink / conduit. The simple `yield` is implemented as `\o -> yieldOr o (return ())` where you can replace `return ()` with your finalization code.

If you have no finalization job to do in this conduit then you can use [`awaitForever`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.6.2/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v:awaitForever) instead.

Quite all of the questions you may have are concluded in a tutorial written by the author of conduit package, I recommand read that first: [Conduit Overview](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview)

Comment: But is it possible to return `Nothing` if there is no value _right now_? So the subsequent call could return `Just` again when the value is ready?

Comment: @AlexeyRaga Fundamentally, no it's not possible. Behind the scene Conduits works backwards: you ask a value from the final sink, the sink asks a value from the upstream conduit / source and so on. They will wait for one another. When there is no value left, the upstream will in fact pass a speical "No value" indicator to the downstream, so they will know they don't have to wait anymore.